# If a native mobile app opens a browser, does it share local storage with the native browser?

Tags: mobile, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am looking at implementing a native mobile application that will have some authentication on it. This authentication data will be stored in cookies and local storage. There is already a web application that can be accessed via a browser on the mobile device which has the same authentication (SSO via Azure AD).

If the user is logged in on the mobile device's browser and has a valid session, let's say Safari on iOS, and then they open the native mobile application application, will the native mobile application detect the valid session from the mobile device's browser if it is using the same SSO?

Comment: does this answer pertain? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486576/1913166

Comment: I think it might. I will have to experiment to be sure.